# TypeError when merging dictionaries: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'dict' and 'dict'

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, typeerror, python-3.8

I wanted to join two dictionaries using `|` operator and I got the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'dict' and 'dict'
```

The MWE code is the following:

```
d1 = {'k': 1, 'l': 2, 'm':4}
d2 = {'g': 3, 'm': 7}

e = d1 | d2
```

Comment: Yes, it is encouraged to ask questions and answer them yourself but this one seems very close to [the other question you posted before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62498441/dict-dict-2-how-python-dictionary-alternative-operator-works/62498442#62498442), isn't it?

Comment: In anticipation of the issue which people are going to look for when dictionary merge and update operations are going to become more popular while the exact version of python when they were introduced - not remembered. I am really unsure folks stumbling on the error from the title would dig into the other question/answer.

Comment: Okay, that's kind of what I thought you were doing :D I wasn't aware of this being done in SO but I'm fairly new in the community, so please never mind.

Comment: d1 has a trailing ' at the end

Comment: @Alechan: fixed. Thanks for spotting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The merge (`|`) and update (`|=`) operators for dictionaries were [introduced in Python **3.9**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0584/) so they do not work in older versions. You have an option to either update your Python interpreter to Python **3.9** or use one of the alternatives:

```
# option 1:
e = d1.copy()
e.update(d2)

# option 2:
e = {**d1, **d2}
```

However, should you want to update to Python 3.9 you can save some memory updating dictionary `d1` directly instead of creating another dictionary using in-place merge operation:

```
d1 |= d2
```

Which is equivalent of the following in the older versions of Python:

```
d1.update(d2)
```